# reading NetCDF files - tibble columns must have compatible sizes

Tags: r, netcdf, gdal, ncdf4, r-stars

I like to read NetCDF files via `stars::read_ncdf` or `tidync::tidync` but get an error message like

```
#> Error:
#> ! Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.
#> • Size 2: Columns `filter_id` and `filter_params`.
#> • Size 3: Column `chunksizes`.
#> ℹ Only values of size one are recycled.
```

Do you have a suggestion what is going wrong?

```r
url <- "ftp://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/grids_germany/daily/hyras_de/precipitation/pr_hyras_1_2022_v3-0_de.nc"
filename <- "pr_hyras_1_2022_v3-0_de.nc"
download.file(url, filename, mode = "wb")

ncdf4::nc_open(filename)
#> File pr_hyras_1_2022_v3-0_de.nc (NC_FORMAT_NETCDF4):
#> 5 variables (excluding dimension variables):
#>    float lon[x,y]     (Chunking: [600,550])
#>    float lat[x,y]     (Chunking: [600,550])
#>    int crs[]          (Contiguous storage)
#>    float pr[x,y,time] (Chunking: [1200,1100,1])
#>    float number_of_station[time] (Chunking: [1])
#>
#> 3 dimensions:
#>    time  Size:221
#>    x  Size:1200 
#>    y  Size:1100 

raster::brick(filename)
#> class : RasterBrick 

terra::rast(filename)
#> class : SpatRaster 

# read_ncdf   uses package RNetCDF to directly read the NetCDF file
# read_stars  uses the GDAL driver for NetCDF files

stars::read_stars(filename)
#> stars object with 3 dimensions and 1 attribute
#> attribute(s), summary of first 1e+05 cells:

stars::read_ncdf(filename)
#> Error:
#> ! Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.
#> • Size 2: Columns `filter_id` and `filter_params`.
#> • Size 3: Column `chunksizes`.
#> ℹ Only values of size one are recycled.

tidync::tidync(filename)
#> Error:
#> ! Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.
#> • Size 2: Columns `filter_id` and `filter_params`.
#> • Size 3: Column `chunksizes`.
#> ℹ Only values of size one are recycled.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Works for me with this file using the ```stack```method from the raster package: ```raster::stack(filename)```

Comment: The file appears to have 2 variables with different dimensions. As a result, you cannot convert it to a single dataframe. Each variable has to map to a column with tidync, and must therefore have the same number of rows. You will need to subset it to specific variables.

Comment: @RobertWilson thank you very much, could you give me I tip to do it? `raster::brick` and `terra::rast` choose `pr` as varname,  `stars::read_ncdf(filename, var = "pr")` throws the same error message as without `var`. I've added the `nc_open` output

Comment: @akshaymoorthy `raster::brick` and `terra::rast` works too, but it would be easier for further processing with `stars::read_ncdf`

Comment: seems to be RNetCDF related, here I've found the same issue https://github.com/hypertidy/ncmeta/issues/42